# Converting IBM DB2 IXF file to CSV or XML

Tags: c#, python, csv, db2

How do I convert an exported IXF file (using `db2 export`) to a human-readable format, like CSV or XML? I am comfortable with doing it in Python or .NET C#.

Comment: I think you have a better chance of getting a  proper answer if you give us a sample .IXF file to look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PC/IXF format is fairly complex, and is practically unknown to programs outside of DB2. Writing your own PC/IXF parser just to convert an IXF file directly to some other format might take a while. A faster alternative is to issue an IMPORT command on the DB2 server and specify CREATE INTO  instead of INSERT INTO , which will generate a brand new table that can accommodate the contents of the file being imported. This will allow you to run an EXPORT command on the new table to dump the rows to a delimited format.

Answer (score 4):

In case you still want write your own PC/IXF parser, you can take a look at [this project, that converts IXF file to JSON](https://github.com/sapenov/IXF)

Comment: Hi, I tried to use this project which is potentially very valuable but found that it doesn't run. Much of the code doesn't seem to be written in python (for loops written using a C convention for example). Have there been recent changes to this project that I could access? Or a C version?

Comment: @Wiredchop do you have a sample IXF file? I've written this project quite while ago, but left IBM and didn't work on it much since then.

Comment: Nothing I'd be able to share unfortunately. I couldn't even get that far though, even importing the main library caused errors due to syntax problems. I'm not overly familiar with python, should i be using a specific version?

Comment: Slightly tweaked it, so no errors now, but still need a sample IXF file to test it.

Comment: Thanks for your work, we have made some more changes to the code so that it now runs, however no output file. I have put this as an issue in Github (with links to the new code)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look over weekends.

Answer (score 1):

IXF is an old and also well documented file format. It is possible to read and process it, I've done this couple of years ago. So don't let you be discouraged. It's hard, but not too hard for developers.

Today you can find also solutions on GitHub, e.g. [ixfcvt](https://github.com/gxc/ixfcvt)

Answer (score 0):

You said you are confortable with python. Therefore, you can try this :

```
pip install db2ixf
```

You can either use the CLI or the python code.

CLI:

```
db2ixf csv -s '|'  <path/to/your/file.ixf>
```

-s : Separator (Default is `|`)

or:

```
db2ixf parquet <path/to/your/file.ixf>
```

or:

```
db2ixf json <path/to/your/file.ixf>
```

Python:

```
from pathlib import Path
from db2ixf import IXFParser

path = Path('path/to/IXF/file.XXX.IXF')
with open(path, mode='rb') as f:
    parser = IXFParser(f)
    output_path = Path('path/to/output/file.csv')
    with open(output_path, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
        parser.to_csv(output_file)
```

If you need more documentation, you can visit this [link](https://ismailhammounou.github.io/db2ixf/markdown/getting-started/).